# Не удалось запустить MySQL-5.6 - Openserver

Tags: mysql, openserver

**Добрый день.** Помогите пожалуйста. Не могу решить данную проблему.

Openserver 5.4.0 версии. Так же, лога MySQL почему то нет. Писал на форум, разработчик не ответил.

Переустанавливал, все запускалось, но была проблема с PhpMyAdmin, после чего я снова переустановил и появилась такая ошибка:

```
2021-07-09 13:16:13  --------------------------------------------
2021-07-09 13:16:13  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
2021-07-09 13:16:14  Обновление Hosts файла
2021-07-09 13:16:14  Обновление конфигурации MySQL-5.6
2021-07-09 13:16:14  Обновление конфигурации Bind-9.16-Win10
2021-07-09 13:16:14  Обновление конфигурации Sendmail
2021-07-09 13:16:14  Обновление конфигурации PHP_7.0
2021-07-09 13:16:14  Обновление конфигурации PHPMyAdmin
2021-07-09 13:16:14  Обновление конфигурации Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1
2021-07-09 13:16:14  Запуск Bind-9.16-Win10
2021-07-09 13:16:14  Запуск MySQL-5.6
2021-07-09 13:16:14  Запуск Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1
2021-07-09 13:16:14  Проверка состояния сервера
2021-07-09 13:17:24  Не удалось запустить MySQL-5.6
2021-07-09 13:17:24  Сбой запуска!
2021-07-09 13:17:24  --------------------------------------------
2021-07-09 13:17:24  Начало процедуры остановки сервера
2021-07-09 13:17:24  Остановка системных модулей
2021-07-09 13:17:26  Отключение виртуального диска
2021-07-09 13:17:26  Сервер успешно остановлен за 2.125 секунд!
```

*Заранее спасибо.*

Comment: `userdata/logs` - ищите в логах ошибки

Comment: так и прикол в том, что в MySQL-5.6_error.log вообще 0кб, логи есть лишь в Apache, но там проблем нет